# How to append an input field to a form with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

With javascript, I create a hidden form called `form`. Its code is something like this:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.method = "POST";
form.action = targetUrl;
form.target = "_blank";
```

Also, I create an input field called `element1`, like this:

```
var element1 = document.createElement("INPUT");
element1.name="my_text"
element1.value = "blablabla";
element1.type = "hidden";
form.submit();
```

What I'm missing is to append the input element that I have created into the form.

How could I do it?

I have tried with `element1.appendTo('form');` but something is wrong.

Note: I am intentionally avoiding the use of JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You already appended the form to the body, why not use the same code to append to input to the form?

```
form.body.appendChild(element1);
```

Note that you will have to append the input before submitting the form, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with these elements beyond small snippets and will need to access them outside of the current scope you very well might need to give them an id.

You can do this like so:

```
form.setAttribute("id", "hiddenForm");
element1.setAttribute("id", "hiddenElement");
```

Using that ID you can use the DOM API to access them like this:

```
var frm = document.getElementById("hiddenForm");
var elm = document.getElementById("hiddenElement");
```

To append a child of anything to anything else you do the following:

```
// parentNode.appendChild(childNode);
frm.appendChild(elm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use so much of code when it can be done with just one line of code:-
HTML:

```
<div id="form"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("form").innerHTML="put your whole form code here";
```